# reject transaction in metamask from code after few minutes

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3j

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to reject transaction in metamask from javascript or java code after few minutes, if user didn't submit or reject it by himself?

The problem is that the user of my site can submit transaction to my smart-contract within 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible using the web3 API, you would have to suggest these steps to the user through your interface.

Source: I'm a MetaMask developer.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically reject the proposed transaction using another programming language or using the settings of the metamask wallet itself?